# Haskell: accumulator with length, summation, summation of square of a list

Tags: haskell, accumulator

I am new to Haskell and am trying to implement a function with an accumulator, but don't how to correctly use it.

Here is a function using a list of numbers, and return a triple (Int, Int, Int) with length, the sum, and the sum of square of a list by using the built-in function:

```
stats1 :: [Int] -> (Int,Int,Int)
stats1 xs = (length xs, sum xs, sumsq xs)

sumsq :: [Int] -> Int
sumsq [] = 0
sumsq (x:xs) = (^2) x + sumsq xs
```

However, when I tried to use the accumulator way:

```
stats2 :: [Int] -> (Int,Int,Int)
stats2 [] = (0,0,0)
stats2 (x:xs) = (len+1, acc+x, sumsquare + x*x ) (stats2 xs)
  where len = 0
        acc  = 0
        sumsquare = 0
```

I got the error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘(Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)’
                with actual type ‘(Integer, Int, Int)’
    The function ‘(len + 1, acc + x, sumsquare + x * x)’
    is applied to one argument,
    but its type ‘(Integer, Int, Int)’ has none
    In the expression:
      (len + 1, acc + x, sumsquare + x * x) (stats2 xs)
    In an equation for ‘stats2’:
        stats2 (x : xs)
          = (len + 1, acc + x, sumsquare + x * x) (stats2 xs)
          where
              len = 0
              acc = 0
              sumsquare = 0
```

How could I achieve the same goal from `stats1` using an accumulator? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use this accumulator-passing style you first need to declare a recursive function that takes the additionally accumulating parameter. This can be done in the `where` clause, in my example with `recurse`. In the initial call of `recurse`, the tuple is intialized with `(0,0,0)`. In every step (second pattern of `recurse`), the values are accumulated, and the base case (first pattern of `recurse`) returns the resulting tuple.

```
stats2 :: [Int] -> (Int,Int,Int)
stats2 l = recurse l (0,0,0) where
        recurse [] tuple = tuple
        recurse (x:xs) (lenr,sumr,sumsq) = recurse xs (lenr+1, sumr+x, sumsq + x*x )
```

call with:

```
> stats3 [1,2,3]
(3,6,14)
```

The problem with your attempt is that you try to call `stats2` recursively with the tuple as an additional parameter, but you turned that around, so that the tuple is the actual function in that construct (which takes no parameters, hence the error message). Also, if this would work, the values would be initilized with zeros in every step *and* the base case.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little about `l = recurse l (0,0,0)` part? Or any documentation I could follow? Thank you for the solution.

Comment: `recurse` is just a function, here defined as part of the where clause. In `stats2`, this function is called with the initial value of the accumulator, i.e. (0,0,0). The list `l`ist the sole parameter of `stats2`, which is just passed to `recurse` to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulator is a variable that must be passed to the function.

```hs
stats_h :: (Int, Int, Int) -> [Int] -> (Int, Int, Int)
stats_h p [] = p
stats_h (len, sum, sumsq) (x:xs) =
  stats_h (len+1, sum + x, sumsq + x*x) xs
 
stats :: [Int] -> (Int, Int, Int)
stats = stats_h (0, 0, 0)
```

```
λ stats_h (0, 0, 0) [1, 2, 3]
(3,6,14)
λ stats [1, 2, 3]
(3,6,14)
```